# Regex case sensitive (?-i) not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, regex, case-sensitive

I'm trying to extract company names from text.
Sample text:

> "Abc Private Company Ltd. (wholesale) which is largest company."

Regex used:

```
\b(?:(?-i)[A-Z][a-zA-Z()\.]*\s){2,5}
```

It correctly identifies the company name in https://regexr.com/ [image]

But when I try the same in jupyter notebook, I get an error.

```
combined_df['company'] = combined_df['subject_link_text'].str.findall(r"\b(?:(?-i)[A-Z][a-zA-Z()\.]*\s){2,5}")
```

error:
[image]

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the case insensitive flag was `(?i)`, not `(?-i)`.  Try the following:

```py
combined_df['company'] = combined_df['subject_link_text'].str.findall(r"\b(?:(?i)[A-Z][a-zA-Z()\.]*\s){2,5}")
```

Or, just use the `flags` option with `re.I` for case insensitive:

```py
combined_df['company'] = combined_df['subject_link_text'].str.findall(r"\b(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z()\.]*\s){2,5}", flags=re.I)
```

Comment: I want it to be case sensitive, therefore I used (?-i).

Answer (score 0):

TBH the flag seems redundant here, `\b(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z()\.]*\s){2,5}` should do the trick - check @[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nI1Tda/1):

```py
combined_df['company'] = combined_df['subject_link_text'].str.findall(r"\b(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z()\.]*\s){2,5}")
```